# Closed formula $\int_{0}^{1}\prod_{k=0}^n(x+k) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

By computing this integral for different values of $n$ using [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+0+to+1+x%28x%2B1%29%28x%2B2%29%28x%2B3%29%28x%2B4%29%28x%2B5%29%28x%2B6%29%28x%2B7%29%28x%2B8%29%28x%2B9%29%28x%2B10%29%28x%2B11%29%28x%2B12%29%2F13%21), I realized that it appears to exist a constant $C \approx 0.26$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{1}\prod_{k=0}^n(x+k) dx \approx C(n+1)!$$

Question: does exist $C$ such that this equality holds for all $n$?
If not, is it possible to obtain another closed formula for this integral?

I appreciate any comments or hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The coefficient keeps decreasing after $0.26$.  For example, $$ \frac{1}{100} \int_0^1 x^{\overline{100}} \, dx \approx 0.179366, $$ where $$ x^{\overline{n}} = \prod_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (x + k) $$ is the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: @L.F. thanks for pointing this. Maybe there is another way of expressing this integral then.

Comment: In fact (as basically shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3745199) by myself) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\color{red}{\log n}}{(n+1)!}\int_0^1\prod_{k=0}^n(x+k)\,dx=1.$$

Comment: Just a sketch of a slightly different approach.
$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{\Gamma(n+1+x)}{\Gamma(x)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\Gamma(x)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{n+x}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}e^{n\ln t}dt\int_0^1\frac{e^{x \ln t}}{\Gamma(x)}dx$$
Making the substitution $t=ny; \,x=1-z$ 
$$=nn^n\int_0^\infty e^{-n(y-\ln y)}dy\int_0^1\frac{e^{(1-z)\ln (ny)}}{\Gamma(1-z)}dz$$

Comment: Using the Laplace method $\big(f(y)=y-\ln y; \,f'(y)=0$ at $y=1;\,f(1)=f''(1)=1\big)$, and the property $\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-z)}=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\pi}\sin \pi z$
$$I_n\sim n^{n+2}e^{-n}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{n}{2}(y-1)^2}dy\int_0^1e^{-z\ln n}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}\Gamma(1+z)\,dz$$
$$\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^nn\int_0^1 e^{-z\ln n}\left(1-\frac{(\pi z)^2}{3!}+\frac{(\pi z)^4}{5!}-..\right)\left(\Gamma(1)+\Gamma'(1)z+\Gamma''(1)\frac{z^2}{2}+..\right)dz$$

Comment: and we get the result obtained by @metamorphy
$$I_n\sim\frac{(n+1)!}{\ln n}\int_0^\infty\Big(1-\frac{\gamma }{\ln n}\,y+\frac{\gamma^2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}}{\ln^2n}\frac{y^2}{2}+...\Big)e^{-y}dy$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Not a closed form - just an alternate representation which might indicate some additional paths.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\int_{0}^1}&\color{blue}{\prod_{k=0}^n(x+k)\,dx}
=\int_{0}^1\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left[n+1\atop k\right]x^k\,dx
\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left[n+1\atop k\right]\frac{1}{k+1}}
\end{align*}
where $\left[n\atop k\right]$  are unsigned *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)*.